# How to instantiate derived class from base class generically

Tags: c#, class, oop, design-patterns, generics

I have extended the unit converter class given in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852721/1474894
This is what I have now:

```
public abstract class UnitBase<TUnitType, TValueType> where TUnitType : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable
{
    protected static TUnitType BaseUnit;
    protected static TValueType BaseValue;

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<TUnitType, Func<TValueType, TValueType>> ConversionsTo = new ConcurrentDictionary<TUnitType, Func<TValueType, TValueType>>();

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<TUnitType, Func<TValueType, TValueType>> ConversionsFrom = new ConcurrentDictionary<TUnitType, Func<TValueType, TValueType>>();

    public static TValueType Convert(TValueType value, TUnitType from, TUnitType to)
    {
        // If both From/To are the same, don't do any work.
        if (from.Equals(to))
            return value;

        // Convert into the base unit, if required.
        var valueInBaseUnit = from.Equals(BaseUnit)
                                ? value
                                : ConversionsFrom[from](value);

        // Convert from the base unit into the requested unit, if required
        var valueInRequiredUnit = to.Equals(BaseUnit)
                                ? valueInBaseUnit
                                : ConversionsTo[to](valueInBaseUnit);

        return valueInRequiredUnit;
    }

    protected static void RegisterConversion(TUnitType convertToUnit, Func<TValueType, TValueType> conversionTo, Func<TValueType, TValueType> conversionFrom)
    {
        if (!ConversionsTo.TryAdd(convertToUnit, conversionTo))
            throw new ArgumentException("Already exists", "convertToUnit");
        if (!ConversionsFrom.TryAdd(convertToUnit, conversionFrom))
            throw new ArgumentException("Already exists", "convertToUnit");
    }

    public static string GetUnit(TUnitType unit)
    {
        var type = typeof(TUnitType);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        return Enums.GetEnumDescription(unit as Enum);
    }

    public TValueType InUnit(TUnitType unit)
    {
        return Convert(BaseValue, BaseUnit, unit);
    }
}
```

I have concrete implementations like this:

```
public enum TemperatureUnit
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("°C")]
    Celcius,

    [System.ComponentModel.Description("°F")]
    Fahrenheit
}

public class Temperature : UnitBase<TemperatureUnit, double>
{
    static Temperature()
    {
        BaseUnit = TemperatureUnit.Celcius;
        RegisterConversion(TemperatureUnit.Fahrenheit, x => x * 1.8d + 32d, x => (x - 32d) / 1.8d);
    }

    private Temperature(double value)
    {
        BaseValue = value;
    }

    public static Temperature FromUnit(double value, TemperatureUnit unit)
    {
        return new Temperature(Convert(value, unit, BaseUnit));
    }
}
```

I managed to make the ToUnit method generic as part of the base class, but with the FromUnit method I now have one per concrete class (and they would all look very similar). I want to be able to do this:

```
Temperature temperature = Temperature.FromUnit(10, TemperatureUnit.Celcius);
Pressure pressure = Pressure.FromUnit(50, PressureUnit.Bar);
```

...without having to implement FromUnit in each concrete class. Because it is a static method I cannot force the implementation by using an interface. I could have a public constructor in the concrete classes and have something like:

```
public static T FromUnit<T>(TValueType value, TUnitType unit) where T : new()
{
    BaseValue = Convert(value, unit, BaseUnit);
    return new T();
}
```

But I guess it is not that nice, and I will have to go:

```
Temperature temperature = Temperature.FromUnit<Temperature>(10, TemperatureUnit.Celcius);
```

The `<Temperature>` is kind of redundant I think.

Is it possible to implement a generic FromUnit in a better way?

**Edit:**
Basically I want, instead of implementing FromUnit in each sub class:

```
public static Temperature FromUnit(double value, TemperatureUnit unit)
{
    return new Temperature(Convert(value, unit, BaseUnit));
}

public static Pressure FromUnit(double value, PressureUnit unit)
{
    return new Pressure(Convert(value, unit, BaseUnit));
}

public static Speed FromUnit(double value, SpeedUnit unit)
{
    return new Speed(Convert(value, unit, BaseUnit));
}

...
```

...to put generic FromUnit in the base class.

Comment: You really shouldn't have xml comments in your question, fyi. It makes your question longer than necessary.

Comment: OK, I removed the xml comments. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Temperature>` type parameter in your "not-so-nice" solution may seem redundant, but it's actually not. When you write

```
Temperature temperature = Temperature.FromUnit<Temperature>(10, TemperatureUnit.Celcius);
```

The code is actually translated to

```
Temperature temperature = UnitBase<TemperatureUnit, double>.FromUnit<Temperature>(10, TemperatureUnit.Celcius);
```

The compiler is simply nice enough to allow you to use `Temperature` to access that method. Since it's actually calling `UnitBase.FromUnit()`, it has no idea that you actually want to use `Temperature`, and that's why you have to supply it as an additional type parameter.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is not so bad with the extra `<Temperature>` type parameter, but I might stick with having FromUnit implementation in every subclass so I can do 
`Temperature temperature = Temperature.FromUnit(10, TemperatureUnit.Celcius);` and I will be able to keep the constructor of every sub class private. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not push the FromUnit implementation to UnitBase itself:

```
    public static TValueType FromUnit(TValueType value, TUnitType unit)
    {
        return Convert(value, BaseUnit, unit);
    }
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, however with FromUnit I want to return instance of concrete class (e.g. Temperature), not TValueType (e.g. double).